# how to ignore the day part of a date to group data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below query which works, however it seems very untidy and inefficient to me.

My table has two columns: `TDate` & `Sales`

```
TDate      Sales
2016-03-25     5
2016-03-24     8
2016-03-28     7
2016-04-21     2
2016-04-14     1
```

I want to group the data by year and month, i.e. i don't care about the day part of the date. The result (which the query below does give) is,

```
TDate         Sales
201603        20
201604        3
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

```
select left(convert(nvarchar, TDate, 112),6), sum(Sales)
from mytbl
group by left(convert(nvarchar, TDate, 112),6) 
order by left(convert(nvarchar, TDate, 112),6)
```

Comment: i don't see a problem with your query.

Comment: seems good enough to me

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because your code is working - I'd recommend you try asking over at CodeReview.se

Comment: Oh ok cool. I just thought the left(convert three times was inefficient but I don't really know a huge amount about what is going on in the background of sql

Comment: Make sure you always specify a length with nvarchar. Otherwise you get the default length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

convert the dates to first day(any static day) of month and do the grouping

Here is one way using `EOMONTH`

```
select dateadd(dd,1,eomonth(TDate,-1)) as Tdate,sum(sales) 
from mytbl
Group by dateadd(dd,1,eomonth(TDate,-1))
Order by Tdate
```

or use `DATEFROMPARTS`

```
select DATEFROMPARTS(year(TDate),month(TDate),1)) as Tdate,sum(sales) 
from mytbl
Group by DATEFROMPARTS(year(TDate),month(TDate),1))
Order by Tdate
```

This will make sure the dates are properly ordered. In your approach the dates are ordered as string. Both approaches work on `Sql Server 2012` and above

For older versions

```
select DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,TDate), 0) as Tdate,sum(sales) 
from mytbl
Group by DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,TDate), 0)
Order by Tdate
```

Answer (score 2):

For me your query is OK but, maybe use of `DATEPART` instead of string conversion can be result more efficient as time spent.

Try this:

```
select DATEPART(year, TDate) *100 + DATEPART(month, TDate), sum(Sales)
from mytbl
group by DATEPART(year, TDate) *100 + DATEPART(month, TDate)
order by DATEPART(year, TDate) *100 + DATEPART(month, TDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your original query up in a derived table to save some typing, and also make it ANSI SQL compliant:

```
select TDate, sum(Sales)
from
(
    select left(convert(nvarchar, TDate, 112),6) TDate, Sales
    from mytbl
) dt
group by TDate
order by TDate
```

This way you don't have to write the same expression three times! (I.e. easier to adjust/maintain.)

(Same trick can be used for the other answers to the question.)